# How to var_dump a variable inside a yii widget?

Tags: php, yii

**Widget Code:**

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id' => 'wtchgrid',
    'columns'=>array(
        ...
        ),
         array(
            'header' => 'Links',
            'class' => 'zii.widgets.grid.CButtonColumn',
            'template' => '{update}{view}{delete}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'update'=> array(...
                ),
                'view' => array(
                    'label'=>'Vie',
                    'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("share/draw", array("id"=>$data->wtch_id))',
                ),
                'delete' => array(...
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

**What I would like to debug**

I would like to `var_dump($data);`

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `CDataProvider`. I also assume you want to view all the data returned by the DataProvider from database. right?.Because `$data` is a variable that points to the data that needs to be populated in GridView.
If yes then CDataProvider has a property named `data`. It also has a method named `getData()`. So you can use both for this purpose. You can dump it in your controller action or in your view as

```
CVarDumper::dump($dataProvider->data);
```

or

```
CVarDumper::dump($dataProvider->getData());
```